# Order of the sub-conditions in Firebase Remote Config

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config

I would like some explanations concerning Remote Config conditions.
Let's say that I have a condition with the following properties :

- User in audience "MyAudience"
- User in a random percentile >= 50%

Do you know in which order these conditions are applied ?
Are the 50% applied only to the users belonging to "MyAudience" ? 
Or, are the conditions applied in the opposite order i.e. the system picks 50% of all the users and then filter the users which are not in "MyAudience" ?

I realize that statistically the result should be the same, but i would like to know, by curiosity.

Thank you !

Comment: Can you clarify -- are these two separate conditions? That is, I have one condition that's "MyAudience" and a separate condition that's "Random Percentile >= 50". Or is this one condition with two separate properties? That is, I have one single condition that consists of ("User in audience MyAudience AND user in random percentile >= 50")?